# How to get location details from IP address integer value

Tags: java, geolocation

I am converting IP address in to its corresponding number. Now I want to know the location details i.e. long and lat, time zone etc. Is it possible in Java. Do i have to use some external jar for database ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IP addresses themselves don't have location info. However a number of databases/services exist that have this mapping.

See [this blog entry](http://blog.programmableweb.com/2009/03/31/3-free-ways-to-geolocate-by-ip/) for a number of different options. There are a number of APIs and databases to connect to for this, and you have the option of downloading such info locally to avoid remote lookups.

Answer (score 1):

So as others have correctly pointed out an IP address does not contain any of this 'metadata' about location. You will need to either rely on a third party to get this information, retrieve this information yourself, or go without it.  Writing the library to scrape that information should be possible in Java.

Answer (score 1):

```
  ipAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();
  GeoLocation gl = new GeoLocation();
  gl.GetGeoLocationByIP(ipAddress);

String country = gl.Country;
```

[refer](http://www.javaquery.com/2011/10/geolocation-javaquery-api.html)

Answer (score 1):

For getting location from IP address you have to buy the IP databases 
where they will periodically update the IP table.

However if you want, you can get the location details viz city,region,country,longitude,latitude from request header.

It's only available for GAE user.

For more details go through
[GAE ReleaseNotes](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/SdkForJavaReleaseNotes#Version_1.6.5_-_April_24,_2012)

```
public static HashMap<String, Object> getLocationDetails(HttpServletRequest request)
{
    HashMap<String, Object> locationMap =   null; 
    String country  =   "",city="",region="",latitude="",longitude="",temp="",state="",title="",address="",zip="";
    boolean primary =   true;
    try
    {
        locationMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        country     =   request.getHeader("X-AppEngine-Country"); 
        region      =   request.getHeader("X-AppEngine-Region");
        city        =   request.getHeader("X-AppEngine-City");
        temp        =   request.getHeader("X-AppEngine-CityLatLong");
        latitude    =   (temp.split(","))[0];
        longitude   =   (temp.split(","))[1];
        log.info("country>>"+country+"region>>"+region+"city>>"+city+"temp>>"+temp+"latitude>>"+latitude+"longitude>>"+longitude);

        locationMap.put("city"      , city);
        locationMap.put("state"     , region);
        locationMap.put("country"   , country);
        locationMap.put("latitude"  , latitude);
        locationMap.put("longitude" , longitude);
        log.info("locationMap==>"+locationMap);
    }catch (Exception e) 
    {
        log.log(Level.SEVERE,"Exception while getting location"+e.getMessage(),e);
    }
    return locationMap;
}
```